# url rewriting or pagination

Tags: url, session, pagination, url-rewriting

Got some pages  with url rewriting

that appears like this :

`http://www.xx.com/de/xx/kontakt#.ULTZZuT8JuI`

or even without url rewrite

`http://www.xx.com/index.php?page=2#.ULTZu-T8JuI`

this doesen't seems to me like google sessions.
Anyone any idea what's that at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can fully recover the context of your question, but those URL postfixes look to me like ajax cache control tags. (Well, at least if I take it for granted that they are indeed not session IDs. But they can well be that, too; it fully depends on what that "xx.com" actually is. :) )

See the "Make Ajax Cacheable" section on this (aging) [performance research page from Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).